# Don't understand query behaviour

Tags: sql, reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0, sccm

I have a strange behaviour in report builder.
I'm working from an existing dataset and testing my own code in SQL studio before trying in report builder. And I'm lost because I don't understand why the following doesn't work :

```
    SELECT
        v_Collection_Alias.Name as CollectionName,  
        v_Package_Alias.Name as SoftwareName, 
        'Package' as ApplicationType,
        NumberSuccessTable='NumberSuccessTable', sum(case when stat.LastState in (-1,13) then 1 else 0 end) as NumberSuccess,
        NumberInProgressTable='NumberInProgress', sum(case when stat.LastState in (8,9) then 1 else 0 end) as NumberInProgress,
        NumberUnknownTable='NumberUnknown', sum(case when stat.LastState in (0) then 1 else 0 end) as Unknown,
        NumberErrorTable='NumberError', sum(case when stat.LastState in (11) then 1 else 0 end) as NumberError,
        NumberOtherTable='NumberOther', sum(case when stat.LastState in (10) then 1 else 0 end) as NumberOther,
        '' as LastModifiedby,
        '' as Version,
        v_Advertisement_Alias.CollectionID as CollectionID,
        v_Advertisement_Alias.AdvertisementID as DeploymentID,
        '' as CI_ID,
        '' as DeploymentTime,
        v_Advertisement_Alias.PresentTime as ModificationTime,
        '' as AssignmentID

FROM fn_rbac_Advertisement(@UserSIDs) v_Advertisement_Alias  
JOIN fn_rbac_ClientAdvertisementStatus(@UserSIDs)  stat on v_Advertisement_Alias.AdvertisementID = stat.AdvertisementID
INNER JOIN fn_rbac_Package2(@UserSIDs) v_Package_Alias ON v_Advertisement_Alias.PackageID = v_Package_Alias.PackageID 
INNER JOIN fn_rbac_Collection(@UserSIDs) v_Collection_Alias ON v_Advertisement_Alias.CollectionID = v_Collection_Alias.CollectionID
```

This in report builder is prompting me an error because `fn_rbac_Advertisement.Name` need a group by clause. Whereas the following is properly working in the original report :

```
    SELECT
    v_Collection_Alias.Name as CollectionName,  
    v_Package_Alias.Name as SoftwareName, 
    '' as ApplicationType,
    '' as NumberSuccess,
    '' as NumberInProgress,
    '' as NumberUnknown,
        '' as NumberErrors,
        '' as NumberOther,
    '' as LastModifiedby,
    '' as Version,
    v_Advertisement_Alias.CollectionID as CollectionID,
    v_Advertisement_Alias.AdvertisementID as DeploymentID,
    '' as CI_ID,
    '' as DeploymentTime,
    v_Advertisement_Alias.PresentTime as ModificationTime,
    '' as AssignmentID,
    '' as ApplicationType 


FROM fn_rbac_Advertisement(@UserSIDs) v_Advertisement_Alias  
INNER JOIN fn_rbac_Package2(@UserSIDs) v_Package_Alias ON v_Advertisement_Alias.PackageID = v_Package_Alias.PackageID 
INNER JOIN fn_rbac_Collection(@UserSIDs) v_Collection_Alias ON v_Advertisement_Alias.CollectionID = v_Collection_Alias.CollectionID
```

and the following returns me what I want in SQL Studio :

```
Select 
NumberSuccessTable='NumberSuccessTable', sum(case when stat.LastState in (-1,13) then 1 else 0 end),
NumberInProgressTable='NumberInProgress',  sum(case when stat.LastState in (8,9) then 1 else 0 end),
NumberUnknownTable='NumberUnknown',  sum(case when stat.LastState in (0) then 1 else 0 end) AS NumberU,
NumberErrorTable='NumberError',  sum(case when stat.LastState in (11) then 1 else 0 end) AS NumberError,
NumberOtherTable='NumberOther', sum(case when stat.LastState in (10) then 1 else 0 end) as NumberOther
From  v_ClientAdvertisementStatus stat
```

Thanks for any help guys ! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Query:

when you use aggregate function like SUM you need to do a GROUP BY on all your columns that Don't have the aggregate function.

Second Query:

this works because you dont have an aggregate function in your select therefor you dont have to use GROUP BY and report builder can handle the sum and group by for you.

Third query:

this query works because you have aggregate function on all your columns so you dont need to GROUP BY.

Always remember the LOGICAL query processing order is as below:

1.FROM
2.WHERE
3.GROUP BY
4.HAVING
5.SELECT
6.ORDER BY

so your GROUP BY happens before SELECT for that reason when you group by you cant include '' in your group by clause because that column does not exists yet.
so it gives you an error.

Answer (score 1):

When using aggregate functions (such as SUM) you must apply a GROUP BY clause to all columns that are not aggregated eg:

```
GROUP BY v_Collection_Alias.Name,  
    v_Package_Alias.Name, 
    v_Advertisement_Alias.CollectionID as CollectionID,
    v_Advertisement_Alias.AdvertisementID as DeploymentID,
    v_Advertisement_Alias.PresentTime as ModificationTime
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to maintain a lengthy GROUP BY clause you could remove the SUM functions from the SELECT statement and let the report handle the aggregation, with appropriate grouping in Report Builder.

Comment: Hey, didn't know that ! Thx for the information by the way I still can't make it work :( I tried to group by the full line like you did or only the alias which returns me "invalid column name". Can't the variables be a problem here ?

Comment: Sorry, cut and pasted that at the end of my lunch break. Let's lose the aliased/dummy fields in the group by!